# In Bard's Tale 3 (for the Commodore 64), sometimes I am attacked with the message "phazing her". What does this mean?

Tags: commodore-64, the-bards-tale-3-thief-of-fate

In the RPG Bard's Tale 3, sometimes I get attacked with the message"

"So-and-so is hit for xxx damage, phazing him!!"

I can't figure out what this does in addition to just normal damage.  Does it do anything?

Answer (score 1):

"Phazing" is just flavor text, like "draining." It appears to actually be a different damage type in the game, named next to 'critical-hit,' etc, however it does not have any additional effects. The only enemy that uses "phazing" damage are the Vortexes, which are found in Battle 2, and do 145-203 damage.

Comment: In practice, I have been phazed by many many enemies in the game.  Independently, I've been told this attack is intended to drain spell points, but it's hard to say because it's usually associated with a melee attack on party members without hitpoints.